# Can't use other format for date in x axis matplotlib python

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, matplotlib

I can't seem to change the date format in x axis.
I tried different solutions that I found in internet and I keep on seeing this.

[image: Screenshot]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
import matplotlib.dates as dates
import pandas as pd

date = ['2015-1-23','2015-1-24','2015-1-25']
pr = [100,156,134]

date = pd.to_datetime(date)
print date
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time':date,'Value':pr})
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)


ax.plot_date(x=df.Time,y=df.Value)
ax.grid(True)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.savefig('/var/www/html/yoy.png')
```

Comment: What did you try? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Serbitar - I just want that my x axis shows the same value in my list . I tried before the 'Jan.25-2016' format but I got the same format on the picture, thanks

Comment: @Serbitar - is it also possible that we have the item on the list as an axis but still can graph the data even it is hour based(like 3:56:32 pm of 2016-1-24)? I've got a lot of metric data.

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/date_demo_convert.html

Comment: thanks @Mel: it really worked.